# remove Unicode from Dictionary data

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, unicode

I have following dictionary

```
  My_Dict= { u'Apple': [u'A' , u'B'] ,u'orange': [u'C' , u'D'] }
```

I have another dictionary with same data but not in Unicode

```
  Dict= { 'Apple': ['A' , 'B'] ,'orange': ['C' , 'D'] }
```

I am trying to compare both dictionary but its saying both dictionary are not same. I assume its because of that Unicode

Is there any way I can compare both dictionary by removing Unicode from My_dict or converting 'Dict' to Unicode ?

The reason I got Unicode is because I am using S-expression parser. Link to parser module is below for reference. 
    http://sexpdata.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: The two examples are equal; `My_Dict == Dict` is `True`. That's because Python looks only at the contents (using the default system encoding, ASCII) to compare Unicode and byte strings.

Comment: In other words, something *else* is wrong; your actual dictionaries are not equal, not because one has unicode strings and the other byte strings, but their contents are different.

Comment: You are right. Above dicts are same. Actually my dict have numbers like this and error is in those numbers. Python is giving error because its saying that u'9.08' is not equal to '9.080'  Anybody can help on this please ?

Comment: That's because those are not numbers but strings, with different content. Have you tried converting those to `float()`?

Comment: Hi I just striped off trailing zeros from everything. so now Dicts are matching.... I used .rstrip("0") and it worked ! Thanks for all the help otherwise I would have been wasting time in converting Unicode thing from dict

Comment: This question appears to have been answered in comments, as should therefore be closed.

Comment: float() did helped a lot as well. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

To remove Unicode from Dictionary Try:

```
import json, ast
My_Dict= { u'Apple': [u'A' , u'B'] ,u'orange': [u'C' , u'D'] }
print(ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(My_Dict)))
```

Comment: Thanks saved my life, had a Json string and was having problems sending it to a google api thru subprocess+curl, that trick removed the Unicode and formatted the string as a dict and it got accepted by the API.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
some_other_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(My_Dict))
print(some_other_dict)
```

Try this one. It will remove unicode.

Answer (score -1):

For removing unicode you have to convert key and value from unicode.

Check the below code

```
My_Dict= { u'Apple': [u'A' , u'B'] ,u'orange': [u'A' , u'B'] }
Dict= { 'Apple': ['A' , 'B'] ,'orange': ['C' , 'D'] }

My_Dicts={}
for i, v in My_Dict.items():
  ky= i.encode('ascii','ignore')
  if type(v)is list:My_Dicts[ky]=[ item.encode('ascii') for item in v ]
  else: My_Dicts[ky] =v.encode('ascii','ignore')
My_Dict=My_Dicts

print My_Dict
print Dict
```

Output

```
{'orange': ['C', 'D'], 'Apple': ['A', 'B']}
{'orange': ['C', 'D'], 'Apple': ['A', 'B']}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for nested dictionaries of containing all types of datatypes. You will come across this bug with python2.7 https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/issues/61

Answer (score -1):

Maybe perform a json.dumps on both.

```
json.dumps({ u'Apple': [u'A' , u'B'] ,u'orange': [u'C' , u'D'] })
Output: `'{"orange": ["C", "D"], "Apple": ["A", "B"]}'

json.dumps({ 'Apple': ['A' , 'B'] ,'orange': ['C' , 'D'] })
Output: `'{"orange": ["C", "D"], "Apple": ["A", "B"]}'`
```